# Using setInterval function inside angular 2 Component

Tags: angular, closures, setinterval

I am trying to use setInterval inside:  class SignupComponent
so, function () { } can change values to 2 vars of the class which are outscope of function() {} but inscope of the class SignupComponent and I fail. I am using setInterval so I can activate some animation in cycles.
Here is the code:

```
export class SignupComponent  {
      state = 'normal';
      state2 = 'normal';
      v1 = 0;
      myFunc = function (p1){setInterval(function(){
           p1++;
           if (p1%4==0)
        {
            console.log(this.state2);
            this.state == 'normal' ? this.state = 'disappear': this.state
               = 'normal';
            this.state2 == 'normal' ? this.state2 = 'appear': this.state2
               = 'normal' 
        }
    }, 1000)};
```

Problem is that this.state , this.state2 inside setInterval(function(){.... }
Don't refer to state , state2 outside the scope but in he scope of the class. why can't I do this closure?
Is there a way to connect those couple of vars so values will be updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use arrow functions `() => {}` instead of `function() {}` to make `this` point to the current class instance

```ts
myFunc = function (p1){setInterval(() => {
```

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout/setInterval  should be called in this way(for angular user):

```
export class demo implements OnDestroy{
   private _setTimeoutHandler: any;
   private _setIntervalHandler: any;

   mymethod1(){
       this._setTimeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
       // my to do 
       }, 100);
   }

   mymethod2(){
      this._setIntervalHandler = setInterval(() => { 
          myTimer() 
     }, 100);
   }


   ngOnDestroy() {
      clearTimeout(this._setTimeoutHandler)}
      clearInterval(this.__setIntervalHandler);
   }
}
```